# Allocate Console in java applet?

Tags: java, c++, console, stdout, stdin

I have a dll written in C++ which I am injecting to java.exe

I'd like to spawn/allocate a console that I can watch.

I have used this code before I know it works when injecting the dll into win32 applications. But why not work when loaded by java.exe or injected into java.exe?

Here is the console spawning/redirection of std in/out.

```
void InitDebugConsole() {
    int hCrtIn, hCrtOut;
    FILE *conIn, *conOut;

    AllocConsole();
    hCrtIn = _open_osfhandle ((int) GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), _O_TEXT);
    hCrtOut = _open_osfhandle ((int) GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), _O_TEXT);
    conIn = _fdopen( hCrtIn, "r" );
    conOut = _fdopen( hCrtOut, "w" );
    *stdin = *conIn;
    *stdout = *conOut;
}
```

Pretty much my problem is java.exe is somehow blocking the allocation of console.

Comment: What does this have to do with (Java) applets?

Comment: I am injecting a C++ (.dll) file into a java applet (java.exe) thanks. The java applet is on the website.

Comment: *"java applet (java.exe)"* This underlines your confusion, since it is the appletviewer(.exe) that runs Java applets, not java.exe.  But that is beside the point, since you have confirmed that it is a Java applet loading the code.  Note that an applet needs to be digitally signed and trusted, in order to load a DLL.

Comment: No.. my DLL I replaced a DLL in my JRE bin folder to automaticially load by JAVA applets.. and it loads and runs perfectly.. Just cannot spawn a console out of this.